# A positive integer a is self-invertible modulo p if and only if a ≡ ±1 (mod p).

Tags: number-theory

What does it mean that "a positive integer is self-invertible modulo p"?

Comment: $a^2\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.  For $b$ is the inverse of $a$ if and only if $ab\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, and "self-invertible" is intended to mean "is its own inverse."

Comment: @AndreNicolas, why not post it as an answer and push it from unanswered queue?

Comment: @AndréNicolas So, for ab is congruent to p and a=b, a is self-invertible? Right?

Comment: $ab\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ means $b$ is the inverse of $a$ modulo $p$. So $a$ is self-invertible modulo $p$. precisely if $a^2\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Note I have only *defined* self-invertible modulo $p$, as per request. I have not given a proof of the result in the title, leaving that to you since you did not ask for that.

Answer (score 2):

It means that $a^2 \equiv 1 mod p$.